# Mysql update account number with 0's

Tags: mysql

I have a situation where i need to update account number if its length is less than 11, so need to pad it with 0's if it does not meet that.  So, if the number is 123456, need to update it in the db as 00000123456

I have created a Stored Procedure for this and its working fine ,

i need to know is there any better way to do this?

Here is my SP

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `sp_Update_AccountNumber`()
BEGIN
Drop TABLE IF EXISTS temp_table;
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_table (id INT(11),accountnumber varchar(50),
                                                            length int,PRIMARY KEY (`id`));

Insert into temp_table(id,accountnumber, length)
select a.id,a.account_number,length(a.account_number) from accounts a
inner join programs p on a.program_id = p.id
where p.abbreviation = 'UA'
and length(a.account_number) < 11;

set @count = (Select count(*) from temp_table);
While @count > 0 Do 
    set @id = (Select id from temp_table limit 0,1);        
    set @accountnumber = (Select accountnumber from temp_table limit 0,1);        
    set @length = (Select length from temp_table limit 0,1);
    set @newlength = 11 - @length;
    Delete from temp_table where id = @id;

    While @newlength > 0 Do 
        set @accountnumber = concat("0" , @accountnumber);
        set @newlength = @newlength - 1;
    End While;
    Update accounts set account_number = @accountnumber where id = @id;
    set @count = (Select count(*) from temp_table);
End While;
END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
UPDATE accounts
SET account_number = CONCAT(REPEAT('0', 11-LENGTH(account_number)), CONVERT(account_number, CHAR(100)))
WHERE LENGTH(a.account_number) < 11;
```

Comment: hey silly, is there any way we can do opposite of what above is done, can we remove added 0's from account number?

Comment: Actually i updated records but forgot to add one condition so it updated other records too, i need to rollback those records, is there any way to do this?

Comment: yes... try UPDATE accounts SET account_number = CAST(account_number AS UNSIGNED)

Answer (score 1):

use the `zerofill` on your database. It will make 00000000123 when you insert 123.

This is also stated here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/numeric-type-overview.html